# GAP Editor with Syntax Highlighting for Windows

Tags: soft-question, math-software, gap

Can anybody recommend a code editor for Windows which has GAP Syntax Highlighting? 
Thank you

Comment: (+1) It's a question which is good to have answered in a visible place.

Comment: GNU Emacs has a [gap mode](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/Contrib/emacs.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made a very simple, bare-bones GAP mode for [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), which I used for a GAP course I taught. The following installation instructions are from the notes I handed to the students. (But I do not normally use Windows myself, so I haven't verified them for some time).

1. Download http://dev.quendi.de/gap/gap.xml
2. In Notepad++, select “Define your language...” from the “Language” menu.
3. In the resulting dialog, click the “Import...” button.
4. This opens a file selector dialog, from which you should select the `gap.xml` file from step 1.
5. Now close the “User Defined Language” dialog

Comment: Hi Max, I am a bit of a beginner with this stuff, how do I install your GAP mode into Notepad++? Thank you

Comment: I expanded the comment a bit. Let me stress that this is a super-basic mode, it only highlights keywords, and does not even try to highlight any of the gazillion function names of stuff built into GAP (I know several GAP modes for editors try to do this, but I consider it pointless, as those lists of names keep changing anyway).

Comment: (+1) for highlighting keywords only. I've done this for PsPAD (http://www.pspad.com/en/) to replace their highlight mode which exported ~4K names :) and perhaps quikcly became outdated. I am happy to share it (perhaps after testing, since I haven't used it for a while).

Comment: Thanks Max I just tested the instructions and it all works fine. Thanks very much.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov I saw a reference to your PsPad GAP Mode file on the gap-system website, if you are happy to share it I would be interested in testing that out too.

Comment: @Max: bTW, your mode for BBEdit works for TextWrangler.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov yes I know :) see section 0.5 in http://www.quendi.de/ws1415_rechenkurs/sheet0-install.pdf

Comment: Great! BTW, for Windows you may now write http://www.gap-system.org/Releases/ because `.exe` installer is now one of the standard formats (since November 2014).

Comment: @Max: it would be cool to have a mode for Atom :)

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Dunno about that, I don't like Atom particularly (though it seems recent version are not anymore unusably slow). Still, if you want to use it, take a look at https://github.com/ChrisJefferson/language-gap

Comment: @Max thanks - `language-gap` works for me, added to http://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html. I first used Atom maybe a month ago, but used it mostly for Markdown. Will try it for GAP:) Atom is described as "hackable" so the hack I'd like to see is to be able e.g. to select method declaration and see all method installations, or select a name of the function and jump to its documentation. That worked with my old jEdit setup, but it's now broken.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for all answers and comments already there. I have updated the question [Where is the GAP file editor? How do I save GAP programs?](http://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#8.3) from the GAP F.A.Q to list all available modes in one place. Besides [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and [PSPAd](http://www.pspad.com/) for Windows, it lists some other editors as well. In the future, please check it in the GAP F.A.Q. for any updates.

Posting this is as an answer, to save readers' time from walking through all comments and links.

Comment: Hi, I am totally new to GAP. Just to ask that is it possible to use Notepad++ and PSPAd to run GAP? I just downloaded them but I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: @AlanWang you do not use them to _run_ GAP. You can used them to _edit_ GAP code which then you can read in GAP. GAP programs are just plain text files, you can edit them with your favourite text editor, but some editors have additional features like syntax highlighting which make it more convenient. You may be interested in the [GAP Carpentries-style lesson](https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/gap-lesson/), in particular [this episode](https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/gap-lesson/03-func/index.html) explaining `Read` command.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of packages to add GAP mode/syntax highlighting to emacs.

http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/Contrib/contrib.html